# Thread disrupting execution of ASP.net main application

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, exception

I have an ASP.net web app that spawns a process (in a thread). This thread calls a '.dll' to connect to another 'subsystem'.
Problem is, when there are errors connecting to the 'subsystem', it affects my main application (main UI) and I get a 'connection refused message'. I have already put in 'try-catch' error handling routines in my thread. FYI, I would like to treat the thread as a 'Fire and forget' thread.
The thread is spawned when btnSubmit is clicked.
Please refer to trimmed-down extract of code.

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
try
{
    txt_hide.Value = sStatus;
    if (sStatus == "")
    {
        //create thread for posting
        id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Thread th = new Thread(() => postXMLClass.PostXML(sSeqNo));     
        th.Start();  

        sStatus = "Transaction generated..please check posting status..";
        lblMessage.Text = "Transaction Generated...";

    }
    else
    {
        FormView1.DataBind(); //refresh the form 
        clib.Show2("Error generating transaction : " + sStatus, sender);
        lblMessage.Text = "Error generating transaction : " + sStatus;
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Error generating transaction ...: " + ex.Message;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //sqc.Transaction.Rollback();
    lblMessage.Text = "Error encountered...: " + ex.Message;
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (dbc != null) dbc.Dispose();
    if (clib != null) clib.Dispose();
}
```

}

public static void PostXML(string inlinkcode)
{

```
string sToken = "", sXMLOut = "";
Xml.Router.XMLRouter cX = new Xml.Router.XMLRouter();
try
{
    cX.set_Options("com.xml.router.nameServer", appSetArray[0]);
    cX.set_Options("com.xml.router.nameServerPort", appSetArray[2]);
    cX.set_Options("com.xml.router.logicalServerName", appSetArray[1]);
    {          
        sLinkcode = inlinkcode;
        if (sLinkcode != null && sLinkcode != "")
        {
            strxml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
            strxml += "<TableLinkRequest version=\"1.0\"><DocumentLinkStart><Request><StartParams>";
            strxml += "<CmpCode>X</CmpCode><DocCode></DocCode></TableLinkRequest>";
            sXMLOut = cX.Send(sToken, strxml);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception {0}", ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (cX != null) cX.Logoff(sToken);
}
```

}

Comment: There is nowhere near enough detail for us to help you in any way, shape or form. Edit that detail into your question.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. After further searches, I found a post "How to prevent an exception in a background thread from terminating an application?" which is the same as mine.